# Django-registration limit to specific domain email address

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-registration

fairly new to Django and had a question about Django-registration.

I've successfully got it up and registering users correctly with email validation, and now what I would like to do is modify the functionality such that only people with a specific domain email address are allowed to register. So for example, if "xyz.org" was the domain, then only users who attempted to register with a blahblahblah@xyz.org email would be successful.

Below is the relevant code I have so far that handles it all, minus registration success's etc. I think I essentially just need to be able to insert a new type of form object that validates the email field, but I'm unsure how. All verbosity is greatly appreciated, as I'm still a bit rough at this. Thanks!

```
url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')
```

`

```
{% block content %}

{% if form.errors %}
<p>Reg form errors</p>
{% endif %}

<form method="post" action=''>
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}

<input type="submit" value="Send activation email" />
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Override the clean_email method. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-clean-method

Answer (score 3):

You will need to subclass `registration.forms.RegistrationForm` and add a custom [validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/#built-in-validators)  for the email field, a RegexValidator will work.

```
from registration.forms import RegistrationForm

class NewRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NewRegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['email'].validators = [validate_domain]
```

After you have the validator, and the new form, you will have to use this new form for the registration view. In your `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    ...
    url(r'^register/$', register, { 'form_class': NewRegistrationForm }, name='registration_register')
    ...
)
```

I haven't tested this out, but I hope it puts you on the right track!